# .mailmap: can you match on name only, without email, or with wildcard email?

Tags: git

A third-party contributor has commits with their work email address and their personal email address. We're using a `.mailmap` file, and they are mapped to their work mail. They are now getting spam on their work mail because spammers are harvesting `.mailmap` files on GitHub. They have requested to be removed from the `.mailmap` file.

The old `.mailmap` file will still be in the git history, but at least it won't be in `HEAD` any more. That's the best we can do, without `git-filter-branch` and `git push --force` and making many, many forks unhappy.

The generic format of `.mailmap` is:

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> Name you no longer want <email you no longer want>
```

These are also valid:

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> <email you no longer want>
```

and

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep>
```

but is this also a valid format?

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> Name you no longer want
```

Because then we could map their **name** to something like `<name@invalid>`, without having their email in the `.mailmap` file.

I have already tried this, and then did a `git log --use-mailmap`, and I still got the old email address.

I have also tried

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> <>
```

and

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> <*>
```

and

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> <.*>
```

and

```
Name you want to keep <email you want to keep> <**>
```

and none of these work. The only time it worked, is when there is a real email address which exactly matches the email address in the commit, and I don't want to use the real email address in the `.mailmap` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's `.mailmap` files don't support wildcards, and there's no way to map an email address to nothing, since an email address is required for commits.

The syntax you inquire about is valid, but it rewrites the user's name from the old name to the new name, and not to a format without an email.

If your goal is to map the user's work address to something else (or to nothing) without listing it in the file, that isn't possible, since the lookup is keyed primarily by the email address in the commit object itself.  Both you and the user should know that if you just remove the address from the `.mailmap` file, that won't stop the spam because spammers harvest email addresses from repositories as well (via other means), so they can find the email that was in the original commit.  There's therefore no way to stop at least some harvesting of addresses outside of either always using a throwaway address (like GitHub offers) or aggressive litigation against spammers.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it isn't possible. _"the lookup is keyed primarily by the email address in the commit object itself"_ is something I needed to hear from someone else. I had already told the user, and my manager, that it won't stop all spammers, but the user as well as my manager said that this is enough, to stop casual harvesting. It's visible in Google Search now and that spooked them.

Comment: Lesson learned: for third party contributions, _always_ ask for confirmation from the user that their name and email address in the commit object can be used in the `.mailmap` and in automated reporting tools like generating changelogs.

Comment: If you use a Developer's Certificate of Origin and require sign-offs, then this is covered as part of that: it's explicit that your user metadata will absolutely be recorded forever.

Comment: We don't use a Developer's Certificate of Origin, but we do use a Contributor License Agreement. Nevertheless, the request was about the `.mailmap` file, which was not submitted by the contributor, but was generated by our tooling based on their commit metadata.